# How to avoid generated link inside h1 tag when using the GitHub Markdown API?

Tags: github, markdown, github-api, octicons

When I test the GitHub Markdown API (https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/), I'll get a link inside an h1 tag when converting a simple "# Headline".

This is what I send:

`curl --data '{"text":"#Headline","mode":"markdown"}' https://api.github.com/markdown`

This is what I get:

`<h1>
<a id="user-content-headline" class="anchor" href="#headline" aria-hidden="true"><span class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a>Headline</h1>`

This is what I expected to get:

`<h1>Headline</h1>`

Does anyone knows why it happens this way and how to avoid it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's there so you can link directly to the headline. If you don't want your document rendered the way GitHub does it, why are you rendering it with their Markdown service?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering why the do it that way. Do you have any markdown service you can recommend?

Comment: It largely depends on what you're trying to accomplish. The GitHub service is great if you're trying to preview how GitHub will render a file. The [original Markdown implementation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) is good enough for many folks who want to render locally, but some other folks want a more powerful implementation like MultiMarkdown or Pandoc. In any case, [tool recommendations are off topic on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Maybe you could reword your question so it's more objective?

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the `mode` parameter to `gfm` (the default is `markdown`).

https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/